# htaccess - Redirecting pages without extensions using the original URL as parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to set up a rewrite rule that will customers visiting individual product pages (php files) to a single page with the product name passed as a parameter. The old format is

`http://example.com/product` and the new format is `http://example.com/store.php?id=product`.

I can use the following rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+).php$ store.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

to perform the redirect, but it only works if customers include the .php extension in their original request. Similarly, I can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

to eliminate the need for users to input the extension, but I have been unable to successfully combine the two. I tried changing the first rule to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+).$ store.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But this also redirects images and stylesheets, making the site unusable.

What is the best way to change my .htaccess file to meet both of these goals (No required extension, redirects to single page with original page name as parameter)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are all the individual product pages in a different directory than the main shop page where the client clicks on a product to go to that individual product page?

Comment: @Kobbe No, all the pages are in the site's root directory.

Comment: The reason why I ask is that I would take a different approach. If all product pages were in the same directory, you could simply change the name of that directory e.g. by adding an "x" in front of the name. As the server will not find the product, it will trigger a 404. With a custom 404 page, you can fish the parameters out of the URL with $_GET[] and redirect from there and redirect all other request that do not have certain characters in the URL to another 404 page for failed requests that were not for a product page. Do you understand what I'm getting at?

Comment: The problem with the product pages being in the same directory as the main shop page is that you cannot disable all product pages by simply changing the name of the directory they are in.

Comment: Still, if you only have 10 or 20 product pages, you could trigger a 404 by changing the names of the product pages. It's only important to be able to change a directory name if you have hundreds of product pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: https://github.com/fxstar/openshift/blob/master/.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.+?/((img|css|js|media|upload)/.+)$ /$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ store.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```